# Finding the clear spacing distance between two rectangles

Tags: geometry

[image: Image for illustration]

I want to find the clear spacing distance between two rectangles. The clear spacing distances are marked by a red segment connecting two rectangles in the image. (The rectangles are always orthogonal to the x-y axis)

Given

1. Centers of both the rectangles (Center point 1 and center point from the figure)
2. The width and breadth (B1, W1, and B2, W2)

Comment: Can you explain why in the last example, the horizontal distance is to be used instead of the vertical one (between the lower border of the upper right rectangle and the upper border of the the lower left rectangle)?

Comment: A fair description of the rule used here is to choose $\max\{\Delta x,\Delta y\}$

Comment: As expressed your requirements are unclear.  Probably you need to think (and explain) the consequences when overlapping rectangles are eliminated from consideration (making your "clear spacing distance" feasible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With center point 1 at $(x_1, y_1)$ and center point 2 at $(x_2, y_2)$, and presuming you want the greater of the horizontal and the vertical clear spacing, you would use:

$$\max\big(|x_1-x_2|-(w_1+w_2)/2, |y_1-y_2|-(b_1+b_2)/2\big)$$

This takes the axial distance between the centers and subtract half of the appropriate dimension of the rectangles to acquire the clear spacing.

If the result is less than or equal to zero, the rectangles are touching.